# Annoying clicking noise on Asus 1018p, how to turn it off?

Tags: hard-drive, noise

I use Ubuntu 10.10 on my Asus 1018p. Every few second I heare an clicking noise of my hdd. How can I turn it off?

Answer (score 1):

That is not from Linux, that sound is when the HDD puts the head into parking position. I don't think, you can turn it off, although disable the "Turn off HDD when possible" tick in System -> Preferences -> Power Management -> Running on Battery, it may help by parking the head fewer.

Comment: That is defenitely from linux. I have dualboot win and ubuntu. This happens only with linux. Power Management doesn't provide Turn off HDD feature. :)

Comment: @alfalive *Note: anti-Windows joke incoming!* That is because Windows never stops doing useless things in the background! :D Back to seriousness: for me, in Natty, it is "Spin down hard disks when possible". It should be the same in Maverick.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the speaker.  I am having the same problem.  Try muting the speaker and if it works then you have the same problems as me.  Search for popping noise, crackling noise, speak, power
try this.  I did not work for me though.
[Popping noise from laptop speakers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160882/popping-noise-from-laptop-speakers)