# constant beeping in headphones

Tags: 20.04, sound

When using Linux, there is always some very high-pitched squeaking in the headphones. Moreover, during playback of any audio, the squeak disappears

my laptop: acer nitro 5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Constant noise in speakers and headphones](https://askubuntu.com/questions/220223/constant-noise-in-speakers-and-headphones)