# Buzzing sound when speaker idle

Tags: 13.04, speakers, input

i just installed Ubuntu, and am a new user. There is this constant buzzing noise coming from the speakers, when idle. When i play music, the sound goes away, and i hear the music fine.

I tried a few things, but after doing so, the problem is still there and i lost the volume icon from the top right toolbar. :/

any suggestions? The buzzing is irritating beyond belief!

Comment: We need to know some system and hardware specs in order to help you

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/393026/

Answer (score 0):

For me it was skype notification sounds, it would activate it loop endlessly, just now after a clean new install of ubuntu and skype

System Settings>Sound>Applications Sound, try disabling Skype or other programs.

Answer (score 0):

This thread helps fixing my exact problem

[Popping noise from laptop speakers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160882/popping-noise-from-laptop-speakers)

I did this:

```
sudo nano /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/intel-audio-powersave
```

Find the line:

```
INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE=${INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE:-true}
```

Comment it out using `#`. Underneath add the line:

```
INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE=false
```

Save and exit, then restart.