# Buzzing sound when speaker is idle

Tags: sound, audio-jack

The sound appears exactly 5 seconds after speakers become idle, which coincides with Pipewire's "session.suspend-timeout-seconds" default configuration.

So my first attempt was editing 50-alsa-config.lua file. Since it didn't work, I edited the file on all 3 locations listed by the arch wiki: ~/.config/wireplumber/ , /etc/wireplumber/ and /usr/share/wireplumber/.

My next attempt was disabling auto-mute in alsamixer. I have restarted both services and rebooted the PC for good measure. The sound still returns after 5 second of idleness.

Next was intel audio powersave, but the file does not exist even thought the folder does.

This is where I am right now, the posts I have been using are:
[Buzzing sound when speaker idle](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360032/buzzing-sound-when-speaker-idle)
[Popping noise from laptop speakers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160882/popping-noise-from-laptop-speakers)

OS: Ubuntu 23.10
MoBo: Asus Prime z790M-plus with Realtek 7.1 Surround Sound High Definition Audio CODEC*

I am using line out - built in audio (aux cable to speakers), the buzzung sound also happens when I switch the audio output to something different. It does not happen in Windows, and I somehow fixed it in Opensuse KDE settings a couple of weeks ago when I was trying it out.

I am currently permarunning MelonDS because it prevents audio output from going idle, but it is a ridiculous temporal solution. Thanks in advance for your help.