# Buzzing from my speakers when idle Lenovo Y410P

Tags: 13.10, sound, lenovo, soundcard, speakers

I have a buzzing constantly from my speakers when no sound is being played.

If I open sound settings, the speakers POP and then they are silent. (I don't even have to mess with any of the settings.) Once I exit, the speakers POP again and then the buzzing comes back. If I have anything that plays sound on, the buzzing goes away.

I know others have tried turning off automute. I have tried turning off automute in alsamixer but the buzzing does not go away.

I am using a lenovo y410p. Two sound cards show up in alsa mixer: HDA Intel MID and HDA Intel PCH:

**EDIT:**

I should also note that in alsamixer, for sound card 0[MID] I do not have any options for volume control. I only have these in alsamixer for sound card 1[PCH].

**Audio Devices:**

cat /proc/asound/cards
0 [MID            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel MID
                     HDA Intel MID at 0xc2610000 irq 49
1 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xc2614000 irq 50

Sound card information from the terminal can be found here: [my google doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GovPiVcnIm4dtr7UxtX9vhB_KLQYmzjOO6K4sVdDal4/edit?usp=sharing)

**New discovery:**

When my computer is plugged in and I adjust any setting of the volume (mute, unmute, volume up, volume down), the buzzing goes away. As soon as I unplug my computer, the speakers POP and the buzzing comes back.

When I plug the computer in, with the speakers buzzing, the buzzing continues until I adjust any setting of the volume (mute, unmute, volume up, volume down). Then the buzzing goes away.

This suggests to me that "auto-mute disabled" is being overridden on battery power. It seems like auto-mute is activating on battery power regardless of whether or not I have auto-mute disabled. Am I off-base for thinking this?

I don't think this is an electrical issue, since I am dual booting windows and have no such problem with windows.

**EDIT: Sunday March 16, 2014**

Thanks to onecoder4u for pointing out that the *buzzing only happens when the keyboard back-lighting is on dim*, but not when keyboard back-lighting is off or on high.

Ok, I can live with not having my keyboard on dim. This solves the buzzing but not the popping issue. I still get a loud pop from my speakers whenever the computer switches between playing sound and not playing sound. I have no issues at all when my computer is plugged in.

I would mark this question as answered, but I am still having part of the problem.

Comment: Mute the microphone and line-in?

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: Microphone and Line-in are muted.
I have posted the hardware information. Is this what you needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the steps on this post and it completely solved the problem: [Popping noise from laptop speakers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160882/popping-noise-from-laptop-speakers)

The issue was the power save mode on the audio cards. Note, I used nano instead of gedit make changes to the configuration files.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is your issue, but my Y410p with ubuntu 13.10 has this issue.
I get a high pitch noise if I have my keyboard backlight on low brightness.  If the keyboard backlight is off or on high no noise.   I use the fn+space to toggle it.

Comment: Ok. Weird. But this was exactly my problem. Now the only issue is that I still get the loud POP from my speakers when it switches back and forth from playing sound and not playing sound.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, and it was caused by skype.

do you have skype installed? in my case I simply turned off ALL notification sounds on skype and this fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. :) However, I've seen other folks who have suggested this on other questions. I have no application installed that show up in the "applications" section of the sound menu.

Answer (score 0):

Same exact thing happened to me, with Ubuntu (technically Mint) and a Y410P. If other solutions work for you please use them instead, because mine is a really backhanded, last-resort fix. I disabled my speakers and then bought a [USB to stereo audio adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001MSS6CS) and I plug my headphones into that instead of the regular jack. It works, and there is [another way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/652421/lenovo-y50-subwoofer-does-no-work-with-ubuntu-14-04-2-lts/676305#676305?newreg=4cb491f13f8d4cab83e10a4e3d2e7f8e) to get your speakers working again if absolutely necessary, but if you do this then **do not forget** to write down everything you do. It will save your life one day in the future, I'm sure.