# Problem ensuring that changes in HDA Analyzer will remain after restart

Tags: sound, alsa, ibus, speakers, mint

I will try to keep this short: I installed Linux Mint on my Lenovo Y410P, my speakers had problems, I did something, they stopped working but headphones worked, and then I used the solution from miyalys in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/652421/lenovo-y50-subwoofer-does-no-work-with-ubuntu-14-04-2-lts/676305#676305?newreg=4cb491f13f8d4cab83e10a4e3d2e7f8e) thread (the one that starts with "In the referenced..."), and that worked very well to bring back sound to my speakers.

The problem is that whenever I restart my laptop (or even put it to sleep) I have to do everything over again. It only takes a couple minutes, but that's a long time when it's something you have to do every time you login wanting to use speakers. Does anybody know how I can ensure that the changes I make in HDA Analyzer will stay put?

EDIT: When I run HDA Analyzer to make the necessary changes, I am given the following warning message: `(hda_analyzer.py:2970): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/cameron/.config/ibus/bus is not root!` And after finishing making said changes, this message comes up: `Diff was stored to: /tmp/hda-analyze.diff` This is strange to me because when I enter HDA Analyzer I type into the Terminal `sudo python run.py`, so I should be root, right? It seems to me that the problem is with permissions rather than anything else, but I don't know how this could be a problem if I am running HDA Analyzer from a `sudo` command.

EDIT 2: I tried [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1125944) solution, but to no avail. No amount of `gksudo` or deleting `/home/cameron/.config/ibus/bus/` has helped (and now the bus folder has come back in a new, protected form that I don't even have permission to open, let alone delete). Based on the linked solution's consensus, it seems that this is a bug.