# How to get the Lenovo Y50-70 SUBWOOFER to work on Ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, lenovo, alsa

I know theres been quite some posts on this, but Im wondering, whether there still is no solution to this.

I tried making all kinds of changes to `/etc/pulse A)default.pa` and `B)daemon.conf:`

```
A)add "load-module module-combine channels=3 channel_map=front-left,front-right,lfe" at the end
B) ";enable-lfe-remixing = yes" (seems to be no by default for most people / previous versions) to "enable-lfe-remixing = yes"

"; default-sample-channels = 2" to either "; default-sample-channels = 3" and "default-sample-channels = 3"

"; default-channel-map = front-left,front-right" to either "; default-channel-map = front-left,front-right,lfe" and "default-channel-map = front-left,front-right,lfe"
```

I also followed miyalys instructions on [Lenovo Y50 Subwoofer does no work with Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/652421/lenovo-y50-subwoofer-does-no-work-with-ubuntu-14-04-2-lts) and tried all sorts of combinations of the above.

My first question is: How do I revert `"sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC1D0 0x17 SET_POWER 0x0" and "sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC1D0 0x1a SET_POWER 0x0"` in order to set my audio settings back to default.

Secondly and way more importantly:
Please, someone tell me how to get the Lenovo y50-70 subwoofer to work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a new type of solution I've attempted that works for me: https://github.com/dragosprju/y50-subwoofer-linux-enabler. Also, here's the question I posted with answers on which the solution is based on: https://superuser.com/questions/975219/how-to-disable-power-saving-on-my-lenovo-y50s-subwoofer-audio-pins.

Good luck!

Comment: @dragos your scripts didn't work for me on Ubuntu 16.04 on Lenovo Y50. Does anyone have any other solution. I have tried changing parameters in daemon.conf and default.pa, its also not working.