# HDAJackRetask gives new audio settings in alsamixer, but they don't work

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, laptop, alsa, hda-intel

1. Problem(s):

   - The subwoofer does not work on Lenovo Y720 on Ubuntu 18.04, so I have
     changed some pins in `HDAJackRetask`. I tried over 30 combinations,
     most of them gave me the same output, so here is what I found the
     best output with the most settings.

[image]

2. What information I have collected from HDAJackRetask:

   - LFE and surround are two new settings which i did not have before.
     The problem is however, that they don't seem to do anything, I can't
     even adjust the LFE as it has no slider and the surround adjustment
     does no effect at all.
   - In the screenshot there is also the pin `"0x14"` which is the
     internal speaker. If I override that to `"Internal speaker (LFE)"` or
     `"Internal speaker (Back)"` I will suddenly get a lot more sound
     profiles in the Ubuntu settings, 2.1, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1 etc. but no
     matter what I choose it will result in no sound at all, so I stopped
     overriding that.
   - With the HDAJackRetask configuration above, I get two profiles in the
     Ubuntu sound settings. One called `"Analog Stereo Output"` (which is
     my standard) and `"Analog Surroind 4.0 Output"`. Both works.
   - **After reading several posts about this problem and tracking the bug
     on launchpad, it seems that `0x17` is the subwoofer, but turning it on still does nothing.**
3. List of everything I have tried:

   - **HDAJackRetask:** With the description above.
   - **Ubuntu settings**: On a fresh install there is only one kind of ouput speakers, which is `analog built in`, so there is nothing to look up in settings.
   - **File changes:** I added: `load-module module-combine channels=6 channel_map=front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center,lfe`
     at the end of `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and edited a line in `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` from `"enable-lfe-remixing: no" to "enable-lfe-remixing: yes"`. Please note that by doing this I actually got a subwoofer sound setting under settings, but it does not do anything, there is no difference in sound when it's on or off.
   - **GitHub Lenovo Y50 script:** `https://github.com/dragosprju/y50-subwoofer-linux-enabler` without any luck too.
   - **HDA Analyzer:** I tried disabling power saver on the pins, look here for more: [Lenovo Y50 Subwoofer does no work with Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/652421/lenovo-y50-subwoofer-does-no-work-with-ubuntu-14-04-2-lts)
4. The bug can be found at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1553685