# Weird Noise From Left Headphone

Tags: sound, headphones

I hear this weird noise from my left headphone all the time. If I mute it from sound settings, it disappears. However, away from that, I hear that annoying sound all the time that it hurts my brains.

I searched for this problem and tried everything. Didn't fix anything.

I found this: [Popping noise from laptop speakers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160882/popping-noise-from-laptop-speakers)

I tried the first one, couldn't do the second. I can't edit

```
/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
```

I don't know why.

And then I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160882/popping-noise-from-laptop-speakers/160887#160887), but I don't have a line like:

```
options snd-hda-intel power_save=10 power_save_controller=N
```

I also have this error if it matters:

[image]
Thank you very much.

Comment: I can't say much about the actual question but IMHO the error in the image is unrelated.

Comment: @Jan How can I fix the error in the image? What can it cause? Thank you very much.

Comment: That's a different question, please open a new one.

Comment: Let's chat about this [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19039/room-for-tim-and-user1652575). I'll see if I can help you.

Comment: I have a wierd buzz in my left headphone too (using inspiron 15-3521 with Intel HD audio-ALC3221) but I have the same thin in windows, so I guess it's hardware related ??

Comment: Could you explain what type of Headphones you are using and what software is outputting/managing your audio. For example mine would be "USB Wireless Headset, ALSA / PulseAudio system, no applications outputting audio."

Answer (score 0):

Quoting a suggestion...

Your DDX does not work with your current kernel and/or libdrm. There are at least three possible reasons for this: the nouveau DRM kernel module is not loaded, a version mismatch between the Nouveau DRM and libdrm, or KMS being disabled.

First check, that lsmod command lists nouveau. If not, do modprobe nouveau to load the nouveau DRM kernel module, and check the kernel log for possible errors.

If the kernel module nouveau is loaded according to lsmod command, but there are no kernel messages about nouveau at all, then most likely Nouveau KMS is disabled. This prevents the driver to work at all. Possible places to disable KMS are:

kernel command line with: nomodeset, drm.modeset=0, nouveau.modeset=0 or similar
modprobe.conf or modprobe.d/ adding the module options drm modeset=0 or nouveau modeset=0
initramfs carrying the above module options
Check and remove all those that you may find, and retry.

Quote from http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/TroubleShooting/#index1h3

Comment: I do not have nouveau listed in lsmod and I get clicking noise.  can you give more instructions please.  The other stuff does not seem to work.  It is sort of enlightening, because I was certain that the noise was related to the gpu and surprised to find it was a speaker noise.  So this link seems to tie everything together.