# Can't edit system files with gksu gedit gives error when saving could not back up the old copy of the file before saving the new one

Tags: sound, backup, configuration, gedit, system

I am having an issue with my Lenovo Ideapad y410p with the speakers popping and making a ringing sound which I can't seem to figure out how to fix. I found one solution on Ask Ubuntu but I am unable to complete the necessary steps.

The solution is here: [Popping noise from laptop speakers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160882/popping-noise-from-laptop-speakers)

But the second half of the solution requires me to edit two files that I cannot seem to edit.

I have tried editing them in 3 different ways with 3 different editors. I will describe the errors below

using `gksu gedit` I am able to open the files and change the values but cannot save them in gedit and get the following error:

```
Could not create a backup file while saving "/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save"
Could not back up the old copy of the file before saving the new one. 
You can ignore this warning and save the file anyway, 
but if an error occurs while saving, 
you could lose the old copy of the file. Save anyway?
```

and every time I click save anyway, the same message appears and it will not let me edit the file. I have to close without saving.

Online people have suggested unchecking the option in gedit preferences to create backups, which I did in a non-root instance of gedit but it is checked again in the root instance. If I try to uncheck it in the root instance of gedit it will not save the preference change. When I go back into my preferences it is checked again.

Now if I try `gksu mousepad` (my preferred editor anyway) I am not even able to open the file and get the following error:

```
Failed to open the document.

Failed to map /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save' 
/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save': mmap() failed: No such device.
```

And finally if I try to use `sudo nano` or `sudoedit` when I got to write out to the file after saving changes I get an error that says invalid argument. No numbers or codes or letters following that, just invalid argument.

Can anyone tell me how to edit these files?

Update: I also tried using `sudo chmod 755` and `sudo chmod +w` on the files to make sure I had write permissions and then tried

```
sudo echo 0 > /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
```

but I just got permission denied.

Comment: Files `/sys` are not regular files, since `/sys` is not a regular filesystem, but a virtual filesystem provided by the kernel.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect the output using \`sudo\`](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20578/redirect-the-output-using-sudo)

Comment: The article shows you the commands to use: `sudo sh -c 'echo N > /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save'`

Comment: Thanks, muru edited the article shortly after I asked this question. I tried to look this command up in the man page for sudo but couldn't figure out what -c does. I get the use of sh and why to use it to avoid the permissions error. Just don't understand the -c  also that command only works for power_save_controller as it is a y/n file. For power_save I get sh: echo: I/O error. I need to use echo 0

Comment: Also, sudo chmod -w /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save_controller does not work to keep the file from being written to. Every time I restart my system the value is changed back to Y