# Clicking noise from acer r3 131t (left speaker)

Tags: laptop, acer, noise

I have a subtle clicking coming from my laptop?
I have a Acer r3 131t c1yf (32gb HD, 2gb RAM)

It comes from the left speaker.
Windows 10 (dual boot) is very silent.

The Acer Graphics listed on "Details" app is "Intel HD Graphics (Cherryview)

The problem is affected by high graphics mode.  Like if I use a compositor that is more complex than compton. 
The problem also arises if I use Audacity or vlc.

If I am correct, any laptop with Intel HD (Cherryview) should make clicking noises.  I suspect this is a bug or would like to know why and assured it will not break my machine.

Update: I tried disabling automute and I also tried the ideas from 
[This link here](http://www.foxswap.com/computers-and-technology/ubuntu-12-04-clicking-sound-from-speakers/)
repeated here at:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/160882/popping-noise-from-laptop-speakers

There was also an askubuntu link which listed the above instructions and also another one to change the automute to false.  That did not work.

Muting the speakers with the function key works and is almost a fix.  It is a relief that it is not the graphics card or the disk or something else.

There is a mention in the above links to disable the powersave.  I am not able to do this.  The files keep getting overwritten.
I am not sure if this is the fix.
There was also a mention of the nouveau driver not loading.  I suspect this is the case.  It mentioned there was a conflict with graphics and this problem.  I do not know how to load it.

Here it is the text below:

> Your DDX does not work with your current kernel and/or libdrm. There
>   are at least three possible reasons for this: the nouveau DRM kernel
>   module is not loaded, a version mismatch between the Nouveau DRM and
>   libdrm, or KMS being disabled.
>
> First check, that lsmod command lists nouveau. If not, do modprobe
>   nouveau to load the nouveau DRM kernel module, and check the kernel
>   log for possible errors.
>
> If the kernel module nouveau is loaded according to lsmod command, but
>   there are no kernel messages about nouveau at all, then most likely
>   Nouveau KMS is disabled. This prevents the driver to work at all.
>   Possible places to disable KMS are:
>
> kernel command line with: nomodeset, drm.modeset=0, nouveau.modeset=0
>   or similar modprobe.conf or modprobe.d/ adding the module options drm
>   modeset=0 or nouveau modeset=0 initramfs carrying the above module
>   options Check and remove all those that you may find, and retry.

Quote from http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/TroubleShooting/#index1h3

Comment: @markkirby I would agree except it doesn't happen in Windows which is weird.

Comment: @Grammargeek Good point, I missed that, was late when  I voted, thanks for the info, I changed my vote.

Comment: Check my edited post again

Comment: It is the speaker for sure.  I disabled the speaker to mute after loading wine.  I did not try this in mate yet.  However, the fixes for the sound card (I have intel) does not work).  I am quite eager to move to xubuntu or mate especially after downloading such huge file.  Mate seems active too.  I am not sure why graphics has effects on the speaker.

Comment: Do you have an hdmi port?

Comment: yes i have hdmi port